Clio Webhook status suspended
I'm experiencing a recurring issue with setting up a webhook. Every time I attempt to use the webhook, it gets suspended consistently, preventing it from functioning properly.
I've configured the webhook according to the specifications and followed all necessary steps for its implementation. However, regardless of my efforts, the webhook continues to be suspended each time I try to use it.
i tried creating a new one and also updating the fields. If someon could help me, will appreciate!
thank you!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I was passing a wrong field as a request. the custom_field_values{name} doesn't exists
